# Request proxy for file upload using iframe transport

Tags: php, jquery, node.js, jquery-iframe-transport

I have an API which is hosted on another domain on which I wish to upload a file. I tried using jquery.iframe-transport.js but due to CORS I cannot get the output data. Can anybody suggest an alternative. I can use some PHP or node backend on the same domain.

Comment: I had to accomplish a similar task recently.  The process involved will be to upload the file to your web server, and then have your server-side PHP post the file to the other domain.

Comment: @onskee Can you post example code or links for that